# Using isset() but still getting undefined index

Tags: php

In my code below I am trying to retrieve the moduleid, use it to run a query in order to be able to find the module number and module name which belongs to that module id and then include session variables for the moduleid, module number and module name.

The problem I am having is that even though I am using `(isset()`, I am getting undefined index for `$_SESSION['idmodule']` and '$_SESSION['namemodule']`. Now`$_SESSION['module']` is working fine, no problems with that session variable, but the other 2 session variables I am having problem with.

Now the query is correct so there is no problem wih the query, just the problem I am guessing on how I am trying to call the $_SESSION variables.

Below is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['module']))
{
    $query = "SELECT ModuleNo, ModuleName FROM Module WHERE ModuleId = ?";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['module'] );

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($moduleno, $modulename); 

     while ( $stmt->fetch() ) { 
           // session data
          if (isset($moduleno)){
          $_SESSION['idmodule'] = $moduleno;
      }
      if (isset($modulename)){
          $_SESSION['namemodule'] =  $modulename;
            }
    }

    $_SESSION['module'] = $_POST['module'];

}
```

.

Comment: The isset() is being used in wrong place. Remove the ones you added and instead apply them to this line "<th>{$_SESSION['idmodule']}  {$_SESSION['namemodule']}</th>"

Comment: You said that your query is 'correct', but are you sure that `$stmt->execute();` is not failing? Try adding `or die()` to  `$stmt->execute();` & `$stmt->bind_result($moduleno, $modulename);` ==> `$stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error); $stmt->bind_result($moduleno, $modulename) or die($stmt->error);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($moduleno)){
    $_SESSION['idmodule'] = $moduleno;
}
if (isset($modulename)){
    $_SESSION['namemodule'] =  $modulename;
}
```

Both those statements may prevent `$_SESSION['idmodule']` or `$_SESSION['namemodule']` to not be set, so when you reference them later you may get the warning.

To prevent that, later in the code you may need this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['idmodule'], $_SESSION['namemodule']) {
    // your code here
```

The beter way is to clean up a few things:

```
while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
    // inside here $moduleno and $modulename are already set
    $_SESSION['idmodule'] = $moduleno;
    $_SESSION['namemodule'] = $modulename;
}
```

If the module is not found, it would be best to skip the rest of the code and just show an error message.

Comment: so are you saying it should be `if (isset($_SESSION['idmodule'], $_SESSION['namemodule']) {<th>{$_SESSION['idmodule']}  {$_SESSION['namemodule']}</th>}`?
`

Comment: @user1861818 That would be one way; also read the update to my answer.

Comment: I am getting a parse error if I try to do what I mentioned in the comment `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING `

Comment: Can you show me exactly where the if isset() code should go please

Comment: When you're in PHP mode, you need to use `?>` before you can use HTML. @user1861818

Comment: my HTML is in php, it is part of an echo, I updated php/html to show the echo in my code.